# In Powershell, how can I create a mulitple records hashtable?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

In Powershell, how can I create a mulitple records hashtable?
Like these:

```
> Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
> -------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
>     260      25    98568     109684   263    37.80   7896 AcroRd32
>      67       8     1236       3800    30     0.03   2052 atashost
>     122       7     1812       4496    29     0.08   1188 atiesrxx
>     126      10    16204      15936    49            7236 audiodg
>     170      21    12888      21352   106     0.14   5016 CallControl
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be a list of objects in that case and not an hashtable. You can use `New-Object` to create a set of objects with those properties. Something like below:

```
$obj = new-object -type psobject
$obj | add-member -name Handles -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 123
```

and so on for each property. Look at `new-object` for simpler ways of doing the same.

If you already have a list of objects and want a few properties from them, use `Select-Object`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to be able to utilize the Hashtables ability to use Key/Value pairs to easily lookup your data, like by the "ProcessName", then you can do this.  Remember that Powershell is an Object Oriented shell.  You can store objects within objects.  Or in this case, Hashtables within Hashtables.

```
[hashtable] $ProcessDetails = @{Handles=260; NPM=25; 
        PM= 98568; WS=109684; VM=263; CPU=37.80; ID=7896}
$ProcessDetails
[hashtable] $Processes = @{}
$Processes.Add("AcroRd32", $ProcessDetails)
""
$Processes
""
# You can then use the various methods to extract the data.
$Processes.Get_Item("AcroRd32").ID
$Processes.AcroRd32.CPU
$Processes["AcroRd32"].VM
$Processes["AcroRd32"]["ws", "pm", "NPM", "Handles"]
```

Would output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                    
ID                             7896                                                                     
WS                             109684                                                                   
NPM                            25                                                                       
Handles                        260                                                                      
VM                             263                                                                      
PM                             98568                                                                    
CPU                            37.8                                                                     

AcroRd32                       {ID, WS, NPM, Handles...}                                                

7896
37.8
263
109684
98568
25
260
```

You could still create a New-Object to store you Processes details as the Hashtables Value.  A PSObject has an advantage when sending output to a file, the screen, etc.  But if you are doing data lookups for processing, then I like to stick with Hashtables.